# HTML Form not "Posting" user input values to PHP POST Arrary. I am trying to email a form

Tags: php, html, forms

Seemingly simple issue: I have an HTML form:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">

            <h3>Owner Information</h3>
            First Name*: <br />
            <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br />
            Last Name*: <br />
            <input type="text" name="lastname" /><br /><br />
            Are you the owner on title?*: <br />
            <input type="radio" name="titleowner" value="yes" />Yes
            <input type="radio" name="titleowner" value="no" />No<br /><br />
</form>
```

And then here is submit.php:

```
<?php

$admin_email = "aloha@hi.com";
 $email = "hey@gmail.com";
$subject = "subject";
$message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstname'] . " " . $_POST['lastname']);
$message .= "Title Owner? " . htmlspecialchars($_POST["titleowner"]);
$message .= "Mailing Address: " . htmlspecialchars($_POST['mailingaddress']) . "City: " .      htmlspecialchars($_POST['city']) . "State:" . htmlspecialchars($_POST['state']) . "Zip Code" .   (int)$_POST['zipcode'] . "Phone Number:" . strip_tags($_POST['phoneNum']);

//send email
mail($admin_email, $subject, $message);

echo $message;

//Email response
echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
?>
```

The 'echo message' produces this when the user submits:

```
Title Owner? Mailing Address: City: State:Zip Code0Phone Number:Thank you for contacting us!
```

As you can see, the variable for some reason did not populate. Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
enctype="text/plain"
```

is the culprit. The text/plain encoding isn't reliably machine decodable and PHP won't parse it.

Remove the `enctype` attribute entirely.

Comment: Embarrassing how much time I spent not noticing that silly error! Thanks for your help, works flawlessly now.

Answer (score 0):

For POST forms you should use the `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. 
Thats what I'm using for the email forms and it just works.

As Quentin stated in the comments though, the default for a form without file fields is `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`, so if you want to state an enctype explicite, use that one.

Comment: You should only use `multipart/form-data` when you have file inputs. It's inefficient compared to the default.

Comment: I think stating enctype explicite is a good idea. If `multipart/form-data` is inefficient, then what is the default?

Comment: It isn't a good idea, being explicit just means you are adding an opportunity to make a typo that will break things. The default is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.